# Redis Problem compiling ReJSON Module for Windows

Tags: windows, redis, compilation, cygwin, redisjson

I have been trying to find or perhaps compile `ReJSON` Module for my `Windows` machine. I could not find any pre-compiled version of ReJSON Module that's why I thought of compiling it myself. So, I visited their GitHub page for source proceeded with following steps

```
1) Downloaded and Extracted the Zip Folder from https://github.com/RedisJSON/RedisJSON
2) Installed Cygwin with necessary packages
3) located the source directory and executed Make command
```

I got the following error

```
error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mmacosx-version-min=10.6’
```

Which I thought there is some configuration for MacOS in MakeFile. So, I searched all words with `-mmacosx-version-min=10.6` and commented those lines so it could be excluded from Make process. It worked and showed some good progress but at the end now it gives some other errors

```
unrecognised emulation mode: acosx_version_min
```

I thought that I am doing it in wrong way. May be this ReJSON Module is simply not possible for Windows but there is no documentation about its eligibility for Windows. I am nowise in module compiling. Please show me some guidance. I am in desperate need of this ReJSON Module for Windows.

Comment: how are you planing to run it on Windows? With which Redis version?

Comment: @GuyKorland Its version 3.2 from https://github.com/microsoftarchive/redis/releases

Answer (score 2):

I am maintaining [Redis for Windows fork](https://github.com/tporadowski/redis) and when I was working on version 4.0.x I ported ReJSON module to Windows as well, mainly for testing purposes and verification of changes related to modules in Redis for Windows itself. You can find the code here:
[ReJSON module for Windows](https://github.com/tporadowski/rejson)

This fork of ReJSON module should be still working and you should be able to compile it in Visual Studio, perhaps with small adjustments. If you do any - please submit a PR.

Comment: Thanks Tomasz! I already tried compiling it with VS and applied my full potential to make it work for Windows but finally I ended up with no success. I spent almost 7 days of my life on it with different forums and articles and all those led to failure.. Can you please share some pre-compiled version of ReJSON for Windows?

Comment: It is a great pleasure to know if someone is working and maintaining this really important piece of Redis and ReJSON for windows.

Comment: Also it would be really good if you could maintain this Protobuf Module for Redis for Windows at https://github.com/sewenew/redis-protobuf as studies have shown Protobuf is 6x faster than JSON.

Comment: Which version of Redis for Windows are you using? Two weeks ago I released 5.0.9, so perhaps I could update that ReJSON fork with 1) latest changes from upstream original module, and 2) make it work with 5.0.9 as an example of a Windows-ported module.

Comment: I had compiled Redis 5 for windows and it was working great already but yet I was not able to run it with ReJSON. Actually I could not compile ReJSON for windows and that is my main problem. If you could put a compiled version of ReJSON Module for Windows in your Git Releases, that would be just wonderful and we all shall be grateful to you

Comment: I can see now that ReJSON module has switched to Rust language, so perhaps it can be just compiled and will work without major adjustments. I will try that in upcoming weeks (on my TODO list ;) )